# UPDATE FROM runs on entire table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have tried to run an update on a list of records and modify a column based on a few calculations. This is my query (my query actually does a redistribution of amounts into NET and VAT):

```
update transaction_details
set amount = (
    CASE WHEN id = x.netID THEN x.calculated_NET
         WHEN id = x.vatID THEN x.calculated_VAT
    END
    )
from
    (select
        d1.id as 'netHmy',
        d2.id as 'vatHmy',
        round(((d1.amount + d2.amount )/1.18) * 0.18, 2) 'calculated_VAT',
        round((d1.amount + d2.amount )/1.18, 2) 'calculated_NET'
    from transaction_details d1 join transaction_details d2 on d1.id = d2.netID
    where
        1 = 1
        -- multiple conditions
                              ) as x
```

The records selected into X table are `175`, but when I run this query it goes over the entire transaction_details table (over 4.000.000 records).

I know that the order of operations in a query is

```
1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause
```

so I was expecting the updated results to be constrained to the selected 175 records, but apparently it goes over the entire table and the result is `4.354.665 rows affected`.

Is the order of operations different in a UPDATE statement, or I should redesign my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to directly reference the table to be updated in the `FROM` clause if you want any applied filters to work. Something like:

```
update d1 --Or d2?
set amount = (
    CASE WHEN id = d1.netID /*?*/ THEN round((d1.amount + d2.amount )/1.18, 2)
         WHEN id = d1.vatID /*?*/ THEN round(((d1.amount + d2.amount )/1.18) * 0.18, 2)
    END
    )
from
   transaction_details d1 join transaction_details d2 on d1.id = d2.netID
where
    1 = 1
  -- multiple conditions
```

I'm not sure where `netID` or `vatID` are actually meant to come from since you didn't show them in your nested `SELECT`, and I've made a guess that the table to be updated is the `d1` aliased one rather than `d2`. You can probably adapt from the above to hit your actual requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit my query and had to replace column names, but I missed some in the nested select. It's correct now, thank you for pointing it out.